# Find similar results to a given result from single table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with these columns:

> id - Name - Gender - Age - Country

I want to show all people names that have the same `gender`, `age` and `country` with someone in MySQL and PHP.

What would be the best MySQL query for that?

Comment: Please elaborate on what is the problem you are facing. Also, please tell us what approaches you have tried till now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
yt.*
FROM yourTable AS yt
JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM yourTable yt2 WHERE id = $id) yt3
ON yt.Gender = yt3.Gender AND yt.Age = yt3.Age AND yt.Country = yt3.Country
```

**See it perform [live](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6efde/2/0)**

Comment: Thanks tombom, actually this worked as i want, because i want similar results based on given row, like what you have done here: `WHERE id = $id`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT p1.Name
FROM peoplenames p1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT Gender, Age, Country
  FROM peoplenames p1
  GROUP BY Gender, Age, Country
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) p2  ON p1.Gender  = p2.Gender
     AND p1.Age     = p2.Age
     AND p1.Country = p2.Country;
```

This will ignore those names that has no duplicates of `Gender, Age, Country`.

This will give you those names that has the same `Gender, Age, Country`. But if this combination `Gender, Age, Country` only occurs one time, then those name will be ignored.

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6efde/5)

For instance, let us have the following sample data:

```
| ID |     NAME | GENDER | AGE | COUNTRY |
------------------------------------------
|  1 |    Ahmed |   Male |  20 |   Egypt |
|  2 | Mohammed |   Male |  20 |   Egypt |
|  3 |      ali |   Male |  20 |   Egypt |
|  4 |     Saly | Female |  25 |  Jordan |
|  5 |     Sara | Female |  25 |  Jordan |
|  6 | Mohammed |   Male |  60 |   Egypt |
|  7 |   Khalid |   Male |  20 |     KSA |
```

`Ahmed`, `Mohammed`(with id 2) and `ali` have the same `Gender`, `Age` and `Country`: `Male, 20, Egypt`.

The same with `saly` and `Sara`. There five names only will be selected:

```
|     NAME |
------------
|    Ahmed |
| Mohammed |
|      ali |
|     Saly |
|     Sara |
```

Whereas the others:

```
|  6 | Mohammed |   Male |  60 |   Egypt |
|  7 |   Khalid |   Male |  20 |     KSA |
```

Have no others rows having the same `Gender, Age, Country` so they are ignored.

Comment: change this  `) p2  ON p1.Gender = p1.Gender`  to `) p2  ON p1.Gender = p2.Gender` :)

Comment: @tombom Sorry, I missed that. Fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: As my reward I used your sqlfiddle schema in my answer :) Sorry

Comment: @tombom Its OK, It is all yours :) Feel free to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name 
FROM table_name
WHERE Gender  = (SELECT Gender FROM  table_name WHERE id = $x) AND 
      Age     = (SELECT Age FROM  table_name WHERE id = $x) AND 
      Country = (SELECT Country FROM  table_name WHERE id = $x);
```

`$x` would be the particular person's id.

According to @fthiella comment

```
SELECT Name 
FROM table_name
WHERE (Gender, Age, Country) = (SELECT Gender, Age, Country FROM table_name WHERE id = $x)
```

Comment: this will select all the names which are matching the conditions

Comment: Not necessary to query the same table 3 times. Becomes especially ugly when there will be more columns

Comment: @Dasun you could use `WHERE (Gender, Age, Country) = (SELECT Gender, Age, Country FROM table_name WHERE id = $x)`

Comment: again you used where id=$x this condition limits the query to one id

Answer (score 0):

```
select `name` from `tablename` group by `gender`,`age `,`country`;
```